# What is round firewood called?

Tags: wood, burning

I'm looking for the name of this type of firewood. 
These are mostly made from limbs or small trees, about the size of a softball or smaller.
[Here is a link to a youtube video that shows two folks making small round firewood.](https://youtu.be/xGNvbpkI2OE?t=162)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordwood is one term that well applies. It means wood cut into uniform lengths, usually for fuel though it can also apply when that sort of wood is used for construction as in cordwood houses.

The machine itself is a guillotine style wood cutter (not to be confused with guillotine splitter). The one in the video referred to in your question appears quite homemade but there do seem to be commercially produced (or at least commercial quality) guillotine wood cutters around, though they may be custom made by a manufacturer or independent fabricator.

Comment: doesn't seem to be what im looking for. google brought up slices for siding.

Comment: As for other, perhaps old time terms, I've not come across much in the way of specific colloquial labels other than the aptly descriptive 'limb wood' and in my neck of the woods, we generally call them rounds. Cordwood is a good catch all term for this sort of cut wood though it does include both split and rounds, referring to the unit with which such objects are measured. I'm curious why you are seeking such a term. Oddly enough, I think knowing your reasons for seeking could plausibly help the search.

Comment: im just trying to find out about the machine the video shows of the machine shooting out round mini logs. I'm thinking Billet is the term but it just keeps showing large dowels on google with the term billet.

Comment: Billet is another fine descriptor for the product of this machine. As far as the machine itself, perhaps you might consider editing the question to include it as part of the question if that is your ultimate goal. I've now edited my answer to include it. That said, I do understand the strategy of asking about the product to get at the machine. However in this particular case, the product is not particularly unique or specific enough to efficiently lead to its maker.